# Which are better: horizontal or vertical vehicle seatmaps?

Tags: usability, gui-design, guidelines

I work for an online travel agency. We have designed interfaces that show vehicle seatmaps for users to select a seat on an airplane or a bus.

Recently the debate has been on which is better: a horizontal or a vertical seatmap. For me, vertical seatmaps are easier to read and easier to manipulate on smaller screens (think selecting your seats on a bus using a tablet).

I'd appreciate very much information on past experiences or usability on this topic.

Comment: Why not detect the form factor and orientation of the screen and orient the seat map accordingly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a user select a seat, she is having a device in front of her imagining the ride she is about to take. For the user the forward direction is in the line of sight and away in the distance. Thinking of going forward makes a vertical seat map more natural. The front of the vehicle need to point upward to make this analogy work.

The horizontal representation makes no sense since there is no natural direction for the vehicle. Some user would say right, others to the left. To minimize cognitive load and remove ambiguity, use the vertical upward pointing seat map.

Answer (score 1):

Try both and see which one users respond to better.  A/B testing is a good way to do that.

As for my personal thought, I'd think vertical is better. Much like maps have North at the top, I would think of the vehicle front as the top.  This is the way I've seen airlines do it, so perhaps it's just my past experience has trained me that way.

Answer (score 0):

I think either way is suitable as long as its clear which is the front and which is the rear.

You started to allude to a good point though when you said "For me, vertical seatmaps are easier to read and easier to manipulate on smaller screens." Considering the context of where it is placed and who the audience is may reveal what is the best option.

Comment: You have a point. I've purchased bus tickets where the seatmap is horizontal and well, I was able to do it. I've also noticed that bus ticket sellers use POP systems that display horizontal seatmaps. 
However, in both cases only one seatmap is shown at a time: one screen for departure, and move to the next screen for return. 
In our case, we decided to use a single page to select all your seats. So we wondered if the horizontal layout would cause usability problems

Answer (score 0):

When I think of sitting "next to" someone, I think of horizontal rows. Having my seat mate either "under me" or "over me" doesn't mesh as well with my visualization of the real world. But that's just an opinion, not a measured observation. To be practical, execute a usability study.

Comment: Thanks! You're right! It's easier to picture rows horizontally than vertically. Maybe it makes it easier to spot empty spaces. Again, like you said, its our opinion, but it makes a lot of sense to me.